# Property of the diagonal operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\lambda = (\lambda_1, \lambda_2, ....)$ and $T_{\lambda}: l_p \to l_p$ be the operator ancting obvious way.

The exercise is to prove that it's isomorphism iff the closure  $\overline {\lambda_n}$ does not contain $0$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

And some generalization: 
The operator (acting in obvious way) $T_f : L_p(X, \mu) \to L_p(X, \mu)$, $f \in L_{\infty}(X, \mu) $ is isomorphism iff there is $\theta > 0$ such that $|f(t)| > \theta$ for almost all $t \in X$.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, note that the map $$\varphi: l^{\infty} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}(X)$$ $$\lambda \mapsto M_{\lambda}$$

is an isometric unital isomorphism of Banach algebras endowed with usual norms.

**Propositon**: The map above is a specturm-preserving, i.e. $$\sigma_{\mathcal{B}(X)}(\varphi(\lambda)) = \sigma_{l^{\infty}}(\lambda)$$

But it also  that known that the spectrum of an element $f \in l^{\infty}(S)$ is precisely the set of all elements $x \in S$ so that $|f(x)| > \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.

In the case of sequences the statement above reduces to the fact that $$\sigma(\lambda) = \overline{ \{ \lambda_{n} \} }$$

Can you derive the desired statement now?

P.S. In the case of $L^{p}(X, \mu)$ you can extend the proof along the same lines dealing with an essential spectrum.

Comment: I've already done it and forgot to delete, but thanks.

Comment: @Vladislav By the way, if you find yourself succesfull in resolving your own question, feel free to post an answer -- it might be useful for other users.